# SignalR Android client not Hitting OnConnected method in Server

Tags: android, signalr, signalr-hub

I have the following `TestHub` class in my server.

```
public class TestHub:Hub {
    public override Task OnConnected() {
        //do some work here 
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

and my android client uses the following code to start negotiating with server.

```
//set serverUrl, device_id, logger, serverHub
Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(serverUrl, "device_id="+device_id, false, logger);
HubProxy proxy = connection.createHubProxy(serverHub);
proxy.subscribe(this);
proxy.on("test", new SubscriptionHandler1<String>() {
    @Override
    public void run(String x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}, String.class);
ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(connection.getLogger());
SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = connection.start(clientTransport);
try {
    signalRFuture.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm trying to do some work in server OnConnected() method but it won't hit. i have signalr connection successfully but i want to do some stuff in OnConnected() method. what should i do?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?